# Quiz with countdown enabled upon opening

Tags: mysql, angular, reactjs, typescript, spring-boot

How can I implement an online application which sends emails to selected users. The email contains a link which is available for 3 days after the email was sent. If the user clicks the link before it expires, then they will open a new browser window/tab with the user specific questions and a countdown timer that begins on window load. Starting from that moment, with no pause permitted, they have exactly 1 hour to answer the questions.

The quiz will be submitted by user or automatically with all the answers after the timer reaches 60 minutes.
The user can see the time remaining (updating real time somewhere in the UI).
If possible I would like to implement it in a way that if user accidentally closes the tab, he can open it again with all the answers saved.

We are currently working with Java/Spring Boot(REST API - backend), ReactJS(frontend) + MySQL database.

We do not know exactly how we should search the keywords needed for that email-link-expiration logic. The login method, creation of the quiz and the sending of it to a user along with the database structure is clear for us.
We appreciate any help or implementation ideas (or even technologies)

Comment: No one is going to create this entire solution for you, if you are having specific issues and show your effort people will help. This might be a good start https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vanillajs/05-token-renewal it sounds like your stack is fine. Good luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The ideea was to generate each quizz with a specific random token, like this:

```
04e69b43-f6e2-4a6b-835b-dd58c95e41810
```

Then, send the email to the specific person `myapp.com/quizz?token=token`.
A CRON job in backend will check the creation date of the quizz and check if 3 days have passed without being assessed for the first time and mark the quizz as expired if so(of course, when the link will be assessed and the quizz is expired, an error message will be displayed).

If the quizz is not expired and user clicks, automatically start the quiz and save in the database firstClickTime and expirationTime = firstClick + 1h.The frontend will send each minute a JSON with everything he has written so far to prevent any lost answers if he closes the tab.

Of course there are also some other small details, but this is the whole idea.

Comment: Cody Gray - Thanks for proving my point. Instead of simply remove the lines, you undervoted me on purpose. Here, undervote this too,another comment so I can have even less reputation. Instead of simply telling me that my question is not ok or simply dosent fit here,you just undervote.